# Spring MVC 4 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException - service method fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, h2

I have looked through similar questions on stackoverflow but wasn't able to find an answer, so I apologize in advance for the duplicate question. This error occures in my Spring MVC project when I try to post the register method to, as you might get, registers a new user. I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.d3vs.Integratieproject.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.updateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:83)
    com.d3vs.Integratieproject.web.controllers.RegisterController.processRegistrationForm(RegisterController.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Looking at the error message, the error points to the following method:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
 private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

public User updateUser(User user) throws UserServiceException {
    User u = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    u.setUsername(user.getUsername());
 //   u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
 //   user.setEncryptedPassword(user.getEncryptedPassword());
    user.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getEncryptedPassword()));

   return userRepository.save(u);
 }
}
```

Line 83 is the setUsername method.
At the moment I'm still working with an in memory H2 database where the username and email adres are already known in the H2 database, so when they submit the registration, the user in the database is updated instead of created. Here is a snippet of the H2 db:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, ROLE) VALUES (3, 'sauron', '', 'sauron@mordor.com', 2);
INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, ROLE) VALUES (4, 'aragorn', '', 'aragorn@endor.com', 2);
INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, ROLE) VALUES (5, 'gandalf', '', 'gandalf@ainur.com', 2);
```

As you can see, only the password needs to be added (and encoded first). But that is where the application crashes.

Comment: @Kayaman 
Is nobody replying because it was marked as duplicate or is the answer that obvious?

Comment: Well a bit of both. I don't think the question can be answered now that it's closed, I'd have to reopen it. Does this mean you've been waiting for someone to answer you, instead of reading the duplicate? Solving an `NPE` is the absolute basic issue for a Java programmer. You have no excuse for not being able to solve it.

Comment: @Kayaman
You were right, the error was thrown because the findByEmail(user.getEmail()); on line 83 did not find the e-mail adres, hence the NPE.

Comment: Yup. Some exceptions may leave some space for interpretation, but a `NullPointerException` is straightforward. Of course the path up to the `NPE` can be complicated, but it's relatively easy to backtrack to the source of the problem.

Comment: The GetUsername() method in my User class was set to return null for some reason, so it was quite litteraly  a null pointer !